# Можно ли убрать зависимость от версии сборки?

Tags: c#, .net

Я знаю, что можно в конфигах сделать redirect одной версии сборки на другую.

Однако, можно ли сделать так, что бы без правки конфига я мог подсовывать программе новые версии сборок и она их успешно загружала и работала?

Comment: SpecificVersion="false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Reference Include="ClassLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

Свойство `SpecificVersion` можно установить в "Properties" узла дерева Solution/Project под  References, соответствующего конкретной сборке.

Comment: Что с этим сделать надо?

Comment: Это, как я понимаю, можно прописать в файл проекта?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Свойство `SpecificVersion` можно установить в "Properties" узла дерева Solution под  References, соответствующего конкретной сборке.